# Convergence on the boudary

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider this power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3n)! (2n)!}{(n)!(4n)!}z^n $$
The radius of convergence is $\displaystyle \frac{64}{27}$. But how do we know where it's convergent on the boundary $|z|=\displaystyle \frac{64}{27}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$? Abel's theorem seems to not work here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the radius of convergence of such a hypergeometric series is $\rho=\frac{64}{27}$, $f(z)$ must have some singularity on the circle $\|z\|=\rho$. By using the following form of the Stirling's asymptotics:
$$ n! \approx \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-\frac{1}{12 n}} $$
we have that:
$$a_n=\frac{(3n)!(2n)!}{n!(4n)!}\approx \left(\frac{27}{64}\right)^n \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{25}{144 n}\right) $$
so that the series *is not* convergent for $z=\rho$. On the other hand, once proved that $\left(\frac{64}{27}\right)^n a_n$ converges quite fast towards $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, we have that $f(\rho e^{i\theta})$ behaves like $\frac{\sqrt{3/2}}{1-e^{i\theta}}$, so we have convergence for any point on the boundary, except $z=\rho$.

It is also possible to show that $z=\rho$ is a simple pole with residue:

$$\frac{64\, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{27\, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)} =\frac{32}{27}\sqrt{6}.$$

Comment: What about the other points on the boundary?

Comment: @Wwk: I have just updated my answer. The only singularity of $f(z)$ on the boundary is the simple pole in $z=\rho$.

Comment: $\exp\left(-\frac{25}{144 n}\right) \to 1$ when $n \to \infty$. How can you use the Leibniz' criterion?

Comment: @Wwk: The situation is the same as $\frac{C}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0} C x^n$. We consider the limit as $x\to -1^+$.

Comment: With the same set of asymptotics, it is also possible to directly show that $(z-\rho)f(z)$ is bounded on $\|z\|\leq\rho$, so $z=\rho$ is the only singularity on the boundary and it is a simple pole.

Comment: $\left(\frac{64}{27}\right)^n a_n$ is decreasing, but the limit is $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, not $0$.

Comment: @Wwk: ok, I fixed my argument.

Comment: Then I can't see why it's convergent on $z=-\frac{64}{27}$

Comment: Because the series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n$ is converging for $x=-1+\varepsilon$ and $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1+\varepsilon)^n = \frac{1}{1-(-1)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I don't think you can exchange the order of limit and sum. When x=-1, 1-1+1-1+... is divergent, although its Cesàro summation is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Wwk - ok, $\theta=\pi$ is peculiar, in such a case we have to replace "convergent" with "Cesaro convergent", but that does not change the substance that such a series behaves like the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}C(x/\rho)^n.$